# how to read non-zero part of intelhex file in python using IntelHex package

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, hex-file

I'm trying to read part hex data from an intelhex file using Intelhex package of python 3.6. Using following code I opened the file and tried to convert to dictionary if it helps.

```
ih = IntelHex("data.hex")
mydict = ih.todict()
```

now I have an address

```
startAddress = some value
```

I want to read stored data starting from $startAddress delimited to the zero value. What's the best way to perform that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is the solution. First I converted the IntenHex file to the dictionary:

```
from intelhex import IntelHex
ih = IntelHex("sampleFile.hex")
ihdict = ih.todict()
```

Then iterated through the dictionary from `startAddress` to the place that value is `None`. I stored values in a string named `datastr`.

```
datastr = ""
startAddress = 500300
while ihdict.get(startAddress) != None:
    datastr += str("%0.2X" %ihdict.get(startAddress))
    startAddress += 1
```